react router doesn't work for nested paths in S3
I have react-router-dom set up like below:
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/post/:slug" element={<Post />} />
        // other routes
    </Routes>
</Router>

I have my frontend hosted in an S3 bucket and served through a CloudFront distribution. All of my routes are working except for the "/post/:slug" route. It's weird because if I navigate to a post using the useNavigate hook, it works and loads the post with the correct slug. However, if I reload on the post page or enter the post url directly in the browser (i.e. https://BASE_URL/post/slug/), it just shows a blank page and doesn't seem to be able to identify the route. I'm at a loss because the post route works if I run my frontend locally. It just doesn't work when I deploy with S3 and CloudFront.
For CloudFront host, I forward all paths "*" to my S3 bucket. I also have added an error page to forward to the /index.html root object.

You need to configure the host to return the root index.html file for all page requests into your app. See the CRA deployment docs for S3: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront To be clear, this isn't anything you can fix from the frontend. Can you [edit] to share how you've configured your host/service?

Thanks for your response. I'm using vite, not CRA.

Vite/CRA are irrelevant, that's how you build your artifact... it's the deployment/hosting information that's important, and for that CRA's documentation is still relevant.

Thanks, I'll take a look at the documentation. I've added some more details to my post. Hope it helps!

Why would it work locally and not work on AWS?

Found the fix! I was missing <base href="/" /> in my index.html file.

I believe the path should be "pathname/:id" not "/pathname/:id"

Lol how is this supposed to help

Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.
